# Removing an integer from a list

Tags: java, list

How can I propperly check to see if a List has a defined Integer?

```
private List<Integer> itemsToDrop = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private int lastRateAdded, lastDropAdded;


if(itemsToDrop.contains(lastDropAdded))
{
      itemsToDrop.remove(lastDropAdded);

}
itemsToDrop.add(DropConfig.itemDrops[npc][1]);
lastRateAdded = itemRate;
lastDropAdded = DropConfig.itemDrops[npc][1];
```

However, this is throwing the following error

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 526, Size: 1

SO, I need to figure out how to properly check to see if an Integer is stored in the List or not

Comment: It looks like the exception is actually related to your DropConfig class rather than the list.

Comment: itemsToDrop is an empty Arraylist , where did you fill datda in it ??

Comment: The exception is related to the list, I've already debugged that down.  @Hussain, I'm not sure. I'm just learning and following the steps that I'm given. Perhaps I missed something somewhere and that's my problem. I'm trying to Add Things to the array list, however the problem is while checking to see if what I want to remove is there, it's retuning true when it's false.

Comment: @Ivaylo, it doesn't even go through the first time, the check automatically returns true and attempts to remove the Integer, even if it's not available.

Comment: This is a very good question. Anybody who downvotes it did not understand it.

Comment: you better write whats do you have as input and what do you want as output

Comment: Are you certain that this code `DropConfig.itemDrops[npc][1]` works OK? Dragondraikk has already proposed that this could be your problem. It is the only obvious usage of indices in arrays in your code, and you have `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Are you iterating through the list or directly removing the element from list? I mean is this the exact code you are facing error in?

Comment: public E remove(int index) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int) 
Removes the element at the specified position in this list. So when you want to remove certain Integer , then you do remove(new Integer(lastDropAdded)). Use remove(Integer) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5, 10, 42));
if (list.contains(10)) {
    list.remove(10); // IOOBE
}
```

The problem with the above code is that you're actually not calling `List#remove(Object)` but `List#remove(int)`, which removes the element at given index (and there's no element at index 10).

Use instead:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5, 10, 42));
if (list.contains(10)) {
    list.remove((Integer) 10);
}
```

That way, you force the compiler to use the `List#remove(Object)` method.

Comment: Just what I was about to write, but you were faster. Upvote. :)

Comment: Great observation :) +1 from me too

Comment: Thank you! I knew I had the code correct ( Well technically ), but this makes sense. Still learning! This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a list

```
private List<Integer> itemsToDrop = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

To answer your questions:

**A**: To check if an integer belongs to a list of integers, you can use `.contains()`

```
itemsToDrop.contains(item)
```

, where item is an integer. This will return `true` or `false`.

**B**: To add

```
itemsToDrop.add(item)
```

**C**: To remove

```
itemsToDrop.remove(item)
```

Edit: Just to be clear, the initial post contained 3 questions which I answered

Comment: The initial unedited question contained 3 questions:
A: How do I check to see if an integer is in a list?
B: How do I add an integer to the list?
C: How do I remove an integer from the list?

Comment: Then apologies for my downvote. The situation wasn't obvious to me. My vote is locked now because it's older than 5h unless you edit the answer.

Comment: That's ok, I edited my answer to clarify. You can always check the edit log for a question. All the best